# Hibernate session.flush() in multi statement transaction

Tags: hibernate

Hi
I am facing strange behavior in hibernate.
I am doing      `ht.saveOrUpdate(myObj)` on an object.
 In the same method  i am next loading a view from database which also contains the above

```
(table) myObj. 
ht.findByNamedParam( from myView ...)  ;
```

But strangely in the loaded view  do not have the recently updated values!
I have also tried to call ht.flush() before the load but still its fetching old values of tabel myObj and not the updated once. session.flush() is not working.

Code is something like :   ( Note: all 3 are in same method and called in same transaction)

```
    ht.saveOrUpdate(myObj);  
    ht.flush();  
    ht.findByNamedParam( from myView....);
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the mapping/annotations?

Comment: The Annotation before method call: 


     @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public myMethod(){}


  Annotation in table :

@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Table(name = "MY_OBJ", schema = "MY_SCHEMA")
public class myObj implements java.io.Serializable {
...


generated by hbm2java reverse ingineering....
}